# Ocean Layer Not Working Properly & Too Laggy

Tags: python, pygame, perlin-noise

Thank you for the help but now the ocean isn't spawning in correctly. I tried making the ocean it's own layer but it over laps the islands (destroys them) I appreciated y'alls help with the color biome problem I had. It is also very laggy and I don't know how to optimise the code.

```
import pygame
import random
import noise

# Initialize Pygame
pygame.init()

# Screen settings
screen_width = 900
screen_height = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Infinite Scrollable World")

# Color palette
colors = {
    "land": (134, 168, 83),   # Light green
    "water": (30, 144, 255),  # Deep blue
    "desert": (244, 164, 96), # Sandy color
    "mountains": (139, 137, 137),  # Gray
    "snow": (255, 250, 250),  # Snow white
    "forest": (34, 139, 34),  # Forest green
    "swamp": (105, 139, 34),  # Swampy green
    "beach": (238, 214, 175),  # Light beige
    "tundra": (192, 192, 192)  # Light gray
}

# Biome definitions
biomes = {
    "water": {"elevation": (0, 70), "temperature": (0.0, 1.0), "moisture": (0.0, 1.0), "color": colors["water"]},
    "beach": {"elevation": (71, 100), "temperature": (0.2, 0.8), "moisture": (0.2, 0.8), "color": colors["beach"]},
    "desert": {"temperature": (0.4, 1.0), "moisture": (0.0, 0.3), "elevation": (101, 200), "color": colors["desert"]},
    "grassland": {"temperature": (0.2, 0.8), "moisture": (0.2, 0.6), "elevation": (101, 200), "color": colors["land"]},
    "forest": {"temperature": (0.0, 0.7), "moisture": (0.5, 1.0), "elevation": (101, 200), "color": colors["forest"]},
    "mountains": {"elevation": (201, 255), "temperature": (0.0, 0.5), "moisture": (0.2, 0.8), "color": colors["mountains"]},
    "snow": {"temperature": (-1.0, 0.0), "moisture": (0.5, 1.0), "elevation": (256, 300), "color": colors["snow"]},
    "swamp": {"temperature": (0.0, 0.7), "moisture": (0.8, 1.0), "elevation": (101, 200), "color": colors["swamp"]},
    "tundra": {"temperature": (-1.0, 0.5), "moisture": (0.3, 0.6), "elevation": (201, 255), "color": colors["tundra"]}
}

# Infinite world generator (using modulo for continuous access)
def generate_world(x, y, size):
    world = []
    for y_ in range(y, y + size):
        row = []
        for x_ in range(x, x + size):
            # Combine multiple Perlin noise layers
            noise_ocean = noise.snoise2(x_ * 0.005, y_ * 0.005, octaves=4)  # Ocean noise
            noise_elevation = noise.snoise2(x_ * 0.005, y_ * 0.005, octaves=4)  # Adjusted scale
            noise_temperature = noise.snoise2(x_ * 0.01, y_ * 0.01, octaves=4)
            noise_moisture = noise.snoise2(x_ * 0.015, y_ * 0.015, octaves=4)  # Adjusted scale

            ocean = int((noise_ocean + 1) * 128)  # Map ocean to 0-255
            elevation = int((noise_elevation + 1) * 128)  # Map elevation to 0-255
            temperature = min(max(noise_temperature, -1.0), 1.0)  # Limit temperature to range (-1.0, 1.0)
            moisture = min(max(noise_moisture, -1.0), 1.0)  # Limit moisture to range (-1.0, 1.0)

            # Assign biome based on elevation, temperature, and moisture
            color = (0, 0, 0)  # Default color
            if ocean < 90:  # If below water threshold, assign ocean color
                color = colors["water"]
            else:  # Otherwise, assign biome color
                for biome_name, info in biomes.items():
                    if elevation >= info.get("elevation", (0, 0))[0] and elevation <= info.get("elevation", (0, 0))[1] \
                            and temperature >= info.get("temperature", (0, 0))[0] and temperature <= info.get("temperature", (0, 0))[1] \
                            and moisture >= info.get("moisture", (0, 0))[0] and moisture <= info.get("moisture", (0, 0))[1]:
                        color = info["color"]  # Assign color within the matching biome condition
                        break

            row.append((elevation, color))  # Referencing 'color' after assignment
        world.append(row)
    return world

# Function to generate a new random seed for world generation
def generate_new_seed():
    return random.randint(0, 1000000)

# Player movement variables
player_x = screen_width // 2
player_y = screen_height // 2
scroll_speed = 5

# World generation parameters
chunk_size = 100  # Adjustable chunk size preference
world_offset = {
    "x": player_x // chunk_size,  # Initial world offset adjusted based on player position
    "y": player_y // chunk_size
}

# Perlin noise parameters for island generation
scale = 0.005
octaves = 4

# Set initial random seed for world generation
random_seed = generate_new_seed()
random.seed(random_seed)

# Game loop
running = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_n:  # Press "N" key to generate a new world
                random_seed = generate_new_seed()
                random.seed(random_seed)
                print(f"Generating new world with seed: {random_seed}")

    # Player movement and world offset update
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        player_x -= scroll_speed
        world_offset["x"] += scroll_speed // chunk_size  # Update world offset for scrolling
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        player_x += scroll_speed
        world_offset["x"] -= scroll_speed // chunk_size
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        player_y -= scroll_speed
        world_offset["y"] += scroll_speed // chunk_size
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        player_y += scroll_speed
        world_offset["y"] -= scroll_speed // chunk_size

    # Generate world chunk around player
    chunk_x = (player_x - screen_width // 2 // chunk_size)
    chunk_y = (player_y - screen_height // 2 // chunk_size)
    world_chunk = generate_world(chunk_x, chunk_y, chunk_size)

    # Clear screen and draw world chunk
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))  # Clear black background
    for y in range(len(world_chunk)):
        for x in range(len(world_chunk[0])):
            elevation, color = world_chunk[y][x]  # Unpack elevation and color tuple
            rect = pygame.Rect(x * 10, y * 10, 10, 10)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, rect)  # Use color from tuple

    # Update display
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Different biomes with different colors and elevations.

Comment: Add some `print`s or use a debugger to find out where the problem arises, e. g. is the data returned by `generate_world` as you expect it?

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the program one line at a time and inspect what the color values are. The debugger is usually already included in your IDE or require some slight configuration depending on your IDE. My guess is that you never assign `color` in `generate_world` due to something wrong in your `if elevation ...` statement.

Comment: Also, don't use both `pygame.display.flip()` and `pygame.display.update()`, as they are very expensive and are both updating the screen. Use just one of them.

Comment: Yea, I implemented the changes recommended and added temp and moisture into the mix of generating the world and it seemed to work

Answer (score 1):

A quick read of your code shows a few weird things in `generate_world`:

- `noise4` is unused (I assume it goes into the `elevation` formula) - that might have a small impact on which elevations actually show up on the map;
- `biome_name` is unused (that one's not really important, maybe you just want it around so you can use `print` to debug - otherwise you can use `for info in biomes.values():`);
- `elevation` is the only variable, so there shouldn't be more than 5 biomes on screen (whichever ones come first for each of your five elevation ranges).

Other than that it seems okay. I ran your code (just had to replace the `noise` module with `perlin_noise` because `noise` wouldn't install) and got this:

[image: 5 colors of noise]

If that's not what you're expecting, maybe you can update the question?

Comment: I added more variables to my code. I added moisture and temperature. But the ocean isn't spawning in idk why

Comment: So I just saw the image, I got it to a point where it generates uniform islands but the ocean does not spawn, its like black like the image you provided and Im trying to fix it